# Is it possible to use more than one client library in the same workspace?

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I purchased a book that uses the python client library on ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04.
I would like to follow the code examples in the book and test them in my catkin workspace; then I would like to convert the python code examples to the Julia client library and test them in Julia.

Should I/can I have the python code files and the Julia code files in the same catkin workspace, or should I have the different client libraries in separate catkin workspaces?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229924/is-it-possible-to-use-more-than-one-client-library-in-the-same-workspace?/) by [TurtleBot_Fan](https://answers.ros.org/users/702/turtlebot_fan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Should I/can I have the python code files and the Julia code files in the same catkin workspace, or should I have the different client libraries in separate catkin workspaces?

There is no need for a different workspace. A workspace is nothing magical, it is essentially just a directory that contains a bunch of sub directories that happen to follow a specific layout and have a few signature files in them (`package.xml`, `CMakeLists.txt`, etc). Because of those files (and their location), tools like `catkin` can provide a few convenient services, but all of that can be done manually as well.

What you do in those directories is up to you.

You do need to keep in mind the ROS [naming conventions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Patterns/Conventions#Naming_ROS_Resources) and make sure your packages are 'good citizens' of your workspace (no two packages with the same name, fi).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1